# Exponent-Characters shown in string

Tags: python, string, exponent

I'm looking for a way, to generate a string, that contains for example "x³". If I don't know the exponent (3), and I want to add it to the string, like this:
"x^"+"3" doesn't work (of course). Is there a way, to add numbers, or possibly even characters as exponent to a string with python?

Comment: Yes. You need to use the proper Unicode encoding which contains the exponent characters you want.

Comment: Where do you need it? If it's for example on a website, then there's html for that.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at [sympy](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/tutorial/printing.html):

```
import sympy
from sympy import init_printing

init_printing()

sympy.pprint(sympy.exp("x^3"))
 ⎛ 3⎞
 ⎝x ⎠
 ℯ    

 sympy.pprint(sympy.exp("x3"))
  x₃
  ℯ
```

Comment: @d0n.key, what do you mean by every string?

Comment: something like a^b to show mathematic formulas better.

Answer (score 2):

I am a little bit confused about the question, but I think you are asking how to do superscript. You can use $$ wrapped around the `^` character in a string.

```
plt.xlabel('Volumetric Flor Wate (m$^3$/s)')
plt.ylabel('Head (m)')
long_title = "Series: 73.77 (m$^3$/s), Head: 55.54 m \n Paraller: 67.065 ($m^3$/s), Head: 45.0132 m"
plt.title(long_title)
```

and it will show like this. [image]

Answer (score 1):

```
print( 'Exponent:\t ' , a , '² = ' , a ** b , sep = '' )
```

This is a line of Python code downloaded from the book "Python in Easy Steps" source code website. I had to Copy and Paste that line of code into the Python 3.5.1 IDLE for it to run because I can't figure out what combination of keystrokes to use to enter the exponent superscript 2 for the variable a.